# How to solve this widget problem on flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

In 'body', two 'child' cannot be in? just one allowed?
If it is, how can I add several widgets like in the picture? ex) ElevatedButton(), Column(children: ?
And there is a red underline below "Column(children: ".
Could someone tell me why this happened?

Comment: You can only have one `child`. But you can have multiple `children`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do the following

```
body: Center(
  child: Column(
     children: [
       ElevatedButton(child: ...)
       Container(child: ....)
       ...
       ]
```